# How to Give manual Acknowledge using JmsTemplate and delete message from Rabbitmq queue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-jms

I am using RabbitMq(with JMS) with jmsTemplate I am able to Consume Message from RabbitMq Queue But it is taking acknowledgment AUTO.

I have Search API for it but not able to find it out.

How can I set manual acknowledgment.

In Below code when Message is consumed from queue I want to call web service with that message and depends on that response from from I want to delete that message from queue.
I have created one project in which I am using Listener and other project with call to read message from queue

first Project:

```
package com.es.jms.listener;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.MessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;

import com.rabbitmq.jms.admin.RMQConnectionFactory;

@Configuration
public class RabbitMqMessageListener {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        RMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new RMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setUsername("Username");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("Password");
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("vhostname");
        connectionFactory.setHost("hostname");

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListener msgListener() {
        return new MessageListener() {
            public void onMessage(Message message) {

                System.out.println(message.toString());
                if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                    try {
                        String msg = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
                        System.out.println("Received message: " + msg);

                        // call web service here and depends on web service
                        // response
                        // if 200 then delete msg from queue else keep msg in
                        // queue

                    } catch (JMSException ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                    }
                }

            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
        container.setDestinationName("test");

        container.setMessageListener(msgListener());
        return container;

    }
}
```

2nd Project:

```
package com.rabbitmq.jms.consumer.controller;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.jms.JmsException;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


import com.rabbitmq.jms.admin.RMQConnectionFactory;

import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;

@Controller
public class ReceiverController {
    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;


    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        RMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new RMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setUsername("Username");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("Password");
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("vhostname");
        connectionFactory.setHost("hostname");

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getdata")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> fecthDataFromRedis()
            throws JSONException, InterruptedException, JmsException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        System.out.println("in controller");

        jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(500L);
        // jmsTemplate.
        String message = (String) jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert("test");

                    // call web service here and depends on web service
                    // response
                    // if 200 then delete msg from queue else keep msg in
                    // queue
        System.out.println(message);

        }

        return new ResponseEntity(message , HttpStatus.OK);

    }

}
```

How Can I do That?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not using a `JmsTemplate`, you are using a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` to receive the message.

If you *were* using the template, you would have to use the `execute` method with a `SessionCallback` since the acknowledgement must occur within the scope of the session within which the message was received.

However, with the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, you simply set the `sessionAcknowledgeMode` to `Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`. See the container javadocs...

```
/**
 * Message listener container that uses the plain JMS client API's
 * {@code MessageConsumer.setMessageListener()} method to
 * create concurrent MessageConsumers for the specified listeners.
 *
 * <p>This is the simplest form of a message listener container.
 * It creates a fixed number of JMS Sessions to invoke the listener,
 * not allowing for dynamic adaptation to runtime demands. Its main
 * advantage is its low level of complexity and the minimum requirements
 * on the JMS provider: Not even the ServerSessionPool facility is required.
 *
 * <p>See the {@link AbstractMessageListenerContainer} javadoc for details
 * on acknowledge modes and transaction options. Note that this container
 * exposes standard JMS behavior for the default "AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE" mode:
 * that is, automatic message acknowledgment after listener execution,
 * with no redelivery in case of a user exception thrown but potential
 * redelivery in case of the JVM dying during listener execution.
 *
 * <p>For a different style of MessageListener handling, through looped
 * {@code MessageConsumer.receive()} calls that also allow for
 * transactional reception of messages (registering them with XA transactions),
 * see {@link DefaultMessageListenerContainer}.
   ...
```

**EDIT**

When using the `JmsTemplate`, you must do your work within the scope of the session - here's how...

First, you have to enable client acknowledge in your template...

```
this.jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Then, use the `execute` method with a `SessionCallback` ...

```
Boolean result = this.jmsTemplate.execute(session -> {
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(
            this.jmsTemplate.getDestinationResolver().resolveDestinationName(session, "bar", false));
    String result = null;
    try {
        Message received = consumer.receive(5000);
        if (received != null) {
            result = (String) this.jmsTemplate.getMessageConverter().fromMessage(received);

            // Do some stuff here.

            received.acknowledge();
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: As I said, you have to use the `execute` method - I added an example.

Comment: Thanks for sharing code.
But I want call web service with the message which will consumed from queue.
In your code the "String value" which is output I will unable to access inside .
If I take it outside and process on it till message will be acknowledge and delete from queue.

Comment: I don't understand your concern; you can call your web service where I say `// Do some stuff here`. You can return whatever you want; I just happened to return the value to the outer code. I have changed the example to return a boolean instead - perhaps that makes it clearer. If you throw an exception, it will return false and the message won't be acknowledged.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. This solved the problem, I have been working for all day yesterday. The other alternative for me which worked was to create a new connection and a message consumer and enable client_ack on the connection but your solution makes it possible to use jmsTemplate for consuming a message in client_ack. Regards.